# Why is the prop "question" undefined? [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to understand why a prop is undefined. I defined it in another React functional component and had no issue there.

My code is:

**App.js** : Here I define one question object with id 1 and name "what".

```
import Questions from './Questions'
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([{ id:1, name:'what'}])

  return (
    <>
      <Questions questions={questions}/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Questions.js** : The "questions" prop is defined here, I have no issue using the accessing its values.

```
import React from 'react'
import Question from './Question'

export default function Questions({ questions }) {
    
    return (
        questions.map(question => {
            return <Question key={question.id} name={question.name}/>
        })
    )
}
```

**Question.js** : Finally, I try to display the name variable of the question prop. However it is undefined.

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Question({ question }) {

    return (
        <div>
            {question.name}
        </div>
    )
}
```

**ERROR Message**:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at Question (Question.js:6:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

It seems that the "question" variable was never defined, why is this? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It is because you passing down a `name` prop to Question component and not a `question`. 
Solution in Questions.js: `return <Question key={question.id} question={question} />`